# Magento quick search not returning all returning all products

Tags: magento

I've searched a keyword e.g "smartwash" there supposed to be 2 items but it's showing 1 items only but the count on the toolbar is right. My magento version is 1.4.2

Thanks

Comment: Here is the site link : http://premierrentals.com.au/catalogsearch/result/?q=smartwash

Comment: rebuild the search index and make sure the products are set to be visible in search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! I added this code on the start of my result.phtml :

```
$_productCollection=$this->_getProductCollection()
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things to check:

- Does the product's visibility allow it to be visible in search?
- Is the product enabled?
- Is the product in stock (Or are out of stock items set to be viewable)?
- Does the product have a price and tax options?
- If it's configurable or bundle, does it have child products/options that are in stock/enabled?
- Have you reindex the Catalog Search Index?
- Have you cleared the Page and Block caches?

Comment: Yes, I've already did all of the items listed. But nothing seems to fix the issue.